# ReadEvent(): "The data area passed to a system call is too small"

Tags: c#, .net, logging

When trying to read the windows logs I sometimes get an EventLogException with the message: "The data area passed to a system call is too small".
I nearly copied the example out of the msdn.

```
EventRecord eventInstance = null;
            try
            {
                eventInstance = logReader.ReadEvent();
            }
            catch (EventLogException e)
            {
                //...
            }
```

I cant see a pattern when and why the error happens.

Comment: Were you disposing your `EventRecord` objects?  If not, maybe that's why you were getting this.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am running into the same damn thing. Cheers.

Comment: @JoeyAdams, I was getting this error sometimes in PowerShell trying to scan through hundreds of thousands of events using [Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogReader] ReadEvent. After adding an explicit call to Dispose() on each EventLogRecord, I haven't seen this error. Thanks.